# Função Ajax não passa pelo success

Tags: ajax, json, web-service

Minha função que faz a chamada do meu web service

```
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value  
     var senha = document.getElementById("senha").value 

      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/Servidor/rest/service/loginCustmerUser/"+ email + ","+ senha,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
           alert(data)
        }, 
        error: function(e){
            alert("Erro: " + e);

        }, 

    });
```

Meu método no webservice

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/loginCustmerUser/{email},{senha}")
public String loginClientUser(@PathParam("email") String email,
        @PathParam("senha") String senha) {
    NotaFiscalBO bo = new NotaFiscalBO();
    CustmerUser cUser = bo.loginCustmerUser(email);


    try {
        boolean validacao = validarCustmerUserLogin(senha,
                cUser.getPassword());
        if (!validacao) {
            cUser = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new Gson().toJson(cUser);
}
```

Retorno do método

{"id":3,"login":"teste","password":"2482e34cc83b09ba9088b2af8bf11866"}

Comment: __NÃO__ use o método GET para esse tipo de requisição!

Comment: Tente retornar o objeto `cUser` normalmente, sem converter em JSON, como visto em http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594945/how-correctly-produce-json-by-restful-web-service

Comment: Onde e como você está usando esta chamada ajax? É no submit de formulário? Pode mostrar o código html envolvido?

Comment: Rafael fiz do jeito que você falou mas não certo, mesmo como POST ou retornando meu objeto vai direto para o error. Dherik estou chamando em um botão com o onclick.

Comment: Rafael retornei o objeto, no browser ele retornar ok, mas no ajax ele vai direto pro erro

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente não há nada de errado em seu código, tente executar a URL 
em um navegador e verifique se irá retornar o usuário logado. Normalmente eu faço dessa forma:

```
@GET
@Path("/loginCustmerUser")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public Response logar(@QueryParam("email") String email,
        @QueryParam("senha") String senha) {

        LoginService loginService = new LoginService();
        Usuario usuario= loginService.logar(email, senha);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).entity(usuario).build();

}
```

Minha URL ficaria assim:
http://localhost:8080/Servidor/rest/service/loginCustmerUser?email=TESTE&senha=TESTE

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara fiz desse jeito que vc falou, estou tomando o seguinte erro -  MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json; charset=utf-8, type=class br.com.servidor.entity.CustmerUser, genericType=class br.com.servidor.entity.CustmerUser.

Comment: Corrigi esse erro com a lib genson colocando o retorno assim - Genson().serialize(cUser); agora meu retorno no browser é esse {"cliente":null,"id":3,"login":"teste","password":"2482e34cc83b09ba9088b2af8bf11866"}. Mas ainda assim vai direto para o erro